# Hibernate fails to update collection of elements in database

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee

**Embedded Class**

```
@Embeddable
public class TeachingExperience {
    private String courseName;
    private String instructor;
    private String description;
}
```

**Entity 1**

```
@Entity
public class CV {
    @ElementCollection(fetch= FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SELECT)
    private List<TeachingExperience> teachingExperiences;
}
```

**Entity 2**

```
@Entity
public class Student {
    @OneToOne(cascade= CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
    private CV cv;
}
```

The CV class stores a list of teaching experiences a person has. There are other fields that should be fetched eagerly, hence the @Fetch annotation.

I use this method to add new teaching experiences to cv of a given student:

```
public static void add (String course, String prof, String desc) {
    TeachingExperience TE = new TeachingExperience(course, prof, desc);
    student.getCv().getTeachingExperiences().add(TE);

    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.merge(student);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
}
```

with this configuration each time i try to add a new Teaching Experience, data stored in DB table, get duplicated first, then new entry get inserted. My database table after two consecutive method call looks like this:

*add('DS', 'Feili', 'TA');*

```
-    DS     Feili      TA
```

*add('AP', 'Ramtin', 'TA');*

```
-    DS     Feili      TA
-    DS     Feili      TA
-    AP     Ramtin     TA
```

I have the same problem when trying to remove an object form the list of teaching experiences and I am not sure which part of my code is the root of this odd behavior.

Your help will be highly appreciated.

**EDIT 1:**

```
@Entity
public class TeachingExperience {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    private String courseName;
    private String instructor;
    private String description;
}

@Entity
public class CV {
    @OneToMany(fetch= FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SELECT)
    @JoinColumn(name="cv")
    private List<TeachingExperience> teachingExperiences;
}
```

Comment: I think you should set the `TeachingExperience` as a `Entity` and also  try `update()` instead of `merge()`. Please let me know what happens after these changes!

Comment: @boomz, thanks for your response. I have already changed the TeachingExperience to an Entity (EDIT 1).
Interestingly after changing merge() to update(), my original problem was resolved but another problem surfaced; removing an item from the list of teaching experience does not propagate to database table.

Answer (score 0):

Try making the TeachingExperience class a full fledged entity with an `@Id` field and a `@ManyToOne` relationship to the CV entity. The use of `@Embeddable` does not seem appropriate in this case.

Comment: I changed my mapping as you advised but the problem remains the same... my new mapping is available under EDIT 1.

Comment: Also try making the colleciton a Set instead of a List and have the TeachingExperience class implement the hashCode() and equals() methods.

Answer (score 0):

For fixing this bug you should use `update()` method instead of `merge()`. `update()` will provide you to undo the deleted items. So if you use `update()`, you problem during the insertion will be fixed and also if you remove something from a list, it will removed from it! But you can see the removed entity in database. If you want to remove all the thing from database, you should use `merge()` for removing and use `update()` for inserting. Also flushing the database regularly after sometimes will help you to solve this problem.